# How can I upload info from Python Tkinter script to MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, phpmyadmin

So I was trying to do a registration panel in tkinter.
I already did a login page, but I'm not so successful with a register page.

This is the code:

```
def register():
uname=username.get()
pw=password.get()
email=emil.get()

savequery = "INSERT INTO `userinfo`(uname, email, pw) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(savequery, [(uname),(email),(pw)])
results = cursor.fetchall()
if results:
    messagebox.showinfo("Nakami - Register","Sikeres regisztráció! Jelentkezz be!")
    os.startfile("Nakami.pyw")
    root.destroy()
else:
    messagebox.showinfo("Nakami - Register","Hiba! (Lehet hogy az adatok már foglaltak)")
    return False
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: You didn't `conn.commit()` the entries

Comment: Other than that; you've given no indication of what's wrong. Does it error? Where is that error?

Comment: What does "not so successful" mean? Why do you think this isn't successful?

Comment: Why do you call `fetchall()` after `INSERT` SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `cursor.fetchall()` will get no record after executing `INSERT` SQL statement.  You need to use `cursor.rowcount` to check whether record has been inserted or not.  Also you need to call `conn.commit()` (assume `conn` is the MySQL connection object) to make the insertion effective.

```py
savequery = 'INSERT INTO `userinfo` (uname, email, pw) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
cursor.execute(savequery, [uname, email, pw])
if cursor.rowcount > 0:
    # insert successful
    conn.commit()  # commit the change to make the insertion effective
    ...
else:
    # insert failed
    ...
```